# Navigation between views Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have simple Click event and want to navigate between views, but I get annoying slide up animation even that I have "false" as a parameter for animation in function. Is there any way to turn of animation effect when browsing between views in Xamarin Forms?
Thank you!

```
  void Button_Clicked_Signup(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Signup(), false);
        }
```

Comment: If you set animation as false for Navigation.PushModalAsync, the effect is different from setting animation as true. I don't have animation when set animation as false, what is your project target?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is doing exactly what you're asking it to do. That annoying slide up animation is called Pushing a Modal which is happening since you are using the `PushModalAsync` function.

You need to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#creating-the-root-page) and understand Hierarchical Navigation.

To fix it, you need to

1. Create a NavigationPage first
2. Pass in your current page into that
3. Use Navigation.PushAsync instead of Navigation.PushModalAsync